# Как дебажить AWS lambda функцию в Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, amazon-web-services

Lambda из примеров от [AWS SAM - hello_world](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html):

```py
import json

import requests


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        ip = requests.get("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/")
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        # Send some context about this error to Lambda Logs
        print(e)

        raise e

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": "hello world",
            "location": ip.text.replace("\n", "")
        }),
    }
```

Когда я вызываю эту функцию, она работает нормально, но когда пытаюсь дебажить, то получаю сообщение об ошибке:

```
/usr/local/bin/sam build Function --template /home/user/PythonProjects/AWS1/.aws-sam/temp-template.yaml --build-dir /home/user/PythonProjects/AWS1/.aws-sam/build
Building codeuri: /home/user/PythonProjects/AWS1/.aws-sam/build/Function runtime: python3.8 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: Function
requirements.txt file not found. Continuing the build without dependencies.
Running PythonPipBuilder:CopySource
Skipping copy operation since source /home/user/PythonProjects/AWS1/.aws-sam/build/Function does not exist

Build Succeeded

Built Artifacts  : build
Built Template   : build/template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Validate SAM template: sam validate
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke -t build/template.yaml
[*] Test Function in the Cloud: sam sync --stack-name {stack-name} --watch
[*] Deploy: sam deploy --guided --template-file build/template.yaml
        
/usr/local/bin/sam local invoke --template /home/user/PythonProjects/AWS1/.aws-sam/build/template.yaml --event "/tmp/[Local] app.lambda_handler-event3.json" --debugger-path /snap/pycharm-professional/302/plugins/python/helpers/pydev --debug-args "-u /tmp/lambci_debug_files/pydevd.py --multiprocess --port 44655 --file" --debug-port 44655
Invoking app.lambda_handler (python3.8)
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-python3.8:rapid-1.59.0-x86_64.

Mounting /home/user/PythonProjects/AWS1/.aws-sam/build/Function as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 0460b513-e188-460a-91eb-87b7d3e51799 Version: $LATEST
pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /home/user/PythonProjects/AWS1/saam1/hello_world/app.py (will have no effect)
pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /home/user/PythonProjects/AWS1/saam1/hello_world/app.py (will have no effect)
Traceback (most recent call last):
END RequestId: 0460b513-e188-460a-91eb-87b7d3e51799
REPORT RequestId: 0460b513-e188-460a-91eb-87b7d3e51799  Init Duration: 0.18 ms  Duration: 662.54 ms Billed Duration: 663 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB 
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
```

Я видел примеры с отладкой с помощью VS, но ничего для Pycharm. А также не нашел никакой полезной информации в [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/invoke-lambda.html).
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

[image]

Comment: Добрый день Dmitry!
Пытаюсь подебажить lambda функцию, использую Pycharm, AWS SAM  и AWS Toolkit.
Также использую пример проекта hello_world от AWS SAM. 
Запуск lambda происходит успешно, однако, когда пытаюсь дебажить эту же функцию, получаю ошибку импорта app.py..

Comment: Перевёл, благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Итак, чтобы это сделать, нужно зайти в конфигурацию вашей лямбда функции, выбрать SAM CLI и поставить галочку в графе Build function inside a container.